# ionic 3 : change button color dynamically : Data Binding is not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working with Ionic3 and I'm trying to set a Dynamic color to a button and I'm surprised to found that there is a problem with Data Binding :

## about.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class AboutPage {

  markers:any[]=Array();
  // many code between those two lines
  test(){
    alert(this.markers.length);
  }

}
```

## home.html:

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-fab  >
    <button ion-fab color="light" (click)="test()" mini [color]="markers.length > 0 ? 'primary' : 'danger'">
       {{markers.length}}
    </button>
  </ion-fab>  

</ion-content>
```

So when I push into the markers the  button content doesn't change but when I click into the button ,the markers.length is updated and the implementation works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Angular ngZone service for this. Read more here: [Angular Zones](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
     this.markers.push(marker);
});
```